How to assign system user to ad account when creating an ad account via Facebook API?
I'm creating an ad account with a system user token, like so:
POST: {business_id}/adaccount
Body:
{
  "name": "Ad Account created by application",
  "currency": "EUR",
  "timezone_id": "47",
  "end_advertiser": {business_id},
  "media_agency": "NONE",
  "funding_id": {funding_id},
  "partner": {app_id}
}

The post request is successful, however, my system user is not being added to the ad account, therefore, the system user does not have permission to manage it.
How can I assign a system user to this ad account via API?

The Facebook support helped me out. I had to call this endpoint after creating the ad account: {act_adaccount_id/assigned_users} with these parameters:
business: business_id
user: App-Scoped User ID
tasks: ["ANALYZE"]
